# Date and time picker with Visual styles enabled-> change background color of the title

Tags: c++, c, winapi, datepicker

I have enabled Visual styles for my application:

```
#pragma comment( linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' \
    name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
    processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' \
    language='*'\"")
```

I can set font for the date in the edit control with following approach:

```
HFONT hf = (HFONT)SendMessage(hwndDateTimePicker, WM_GETFONT, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
if (hf != NULL)
{
    LOGFONT lf = { 0 };

    GetObject(hf, sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf);

    lf.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
    lf.lfUnderline = TRUE;

    hf = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

    SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_DATETIMEPICKER1), WM_SETFONT
        (WPARAM)hf, (LPARAM)TRUE);
}
```

However, trying to use `GetDC` and `SetTextColor` (for example) does not work.

Below image illustrates my goal (color is changed to yellow).

[image]

I have tried subclassing the control, but tjat failed. Here is the code, in case you can spot a mistake:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Decimalni(HWND hwnd, UINT message, 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, 
    UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
        return (LRESULT)((HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH));
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        ::RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, Decimalni, 0);
        return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
    return ::DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


// in WM_INITDIALOG
SetWindowSubclass(hwndDTP, Decimalni, 0, 0 );
```

### QUESTION:

Is there a workaround for my problem?

*Maybe there is a way to get the handle of the edit control and subclass it, for example? Just a thought...*

### EDIT:

This is the best I could have done:

```
// subclass procedure for date time picker
LRESULT CALLBACK DTP(HWND hwnd, UINT message, 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,
    UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps = { 0 };

        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        RECT rcClient = { 0 };
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcClient);
        // Fill client area with desired brush, I used light gray as an example
        FillRect(hdc, &rcClient, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH));

        BITMAPINFO bmi;
        // Create a memory DC
        HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

        // Create a DIB header for parent
        memset(&bmi, 0, sizeof(bmi));
        bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = rcClient.right - rcClient.left;
        bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top;
        bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
        bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
        bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

        // Create a DIB bitmap
        HBITMAP tempBmp = CreateDIBSection(0, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, 0, 0, 0);

        // Select tempBmp onto DC to force size and DIB change on the DC
        HBITMAP oldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, tempBmp);

        // Okay get datetime picker to draw on our memory DC
        DefSubclassProc(hwnd, WM_PRINTCLIENT, (WPARAM)memDC, (LPARAM)(PRF_CLIENT));

        // Transfer the memory DC onto datetime picker DC excluding default white color
        TransparentBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top, 
            memDC, 0, 0, rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top, GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW));

        // cleanup
        SelectObject(memDC, oldBmp);
        DeleteObject(tempBmp);
        DeleteDC(memDC);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
        return 0L;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        ::RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, DTP, 0);
        return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return ::DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

In main windiw/dialog, just subclass the DateTime picker:

```
SetWindowSubclass(hwndOfYourDateTimePicker, DTP, 0, 0);
```

### NEW QUESTIONS:

- You will notice that dropdown button is not visually appealing. Is there a way to correct this?
- ClearType font might give some artifacts, is there a way to solve this?

Comment: When you say you want to set the background of the control, what do you mean? Do you want to make the collapsed edit control red? Or do you want ot make the actual calendar red? Or something else? Does it work without visual styles?

Comment: You could try subclassing the calendar control and handle `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`.

Comment: @andlabs: *When you say you want to set the background of the control, what do you mean? Do you want to make the collapsed edit control red? Or do you want ot make the actual calendar red? Or something else?* See the image in my edited post. *Does it work without visual styles?* I have misread the documentation for the macro I mentioned in my post. No messages/notifications/macros exists that do what I need. I have edited the question to remove the confusion.

Comment: @JonathanPotter would subclassing *the calendar control* do it? I thought `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` was sent to the parent of the DTP itself

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I have tried but failed. Can you see the short code I posted in my edit? Maybe I did something wrong... Thank you.

Comment: @andlabs: Subclassing failed, but maybe I did something wrong ( please review my code in edited post ). I am trying to subclass month calendar now...

Comment: @andlabs: I'm assuming the edit control is a child of the calendar, since it's the calendar that creates it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I have substituted `SetWindowSubclass(hwndDTP, Decimalni, 0, 0 );` in my `WM_INITDIALOG` with `SetWindowSubclass(DateTime_GetMonthCal(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_DATETIMEPICKER1)), Decimalni, 0, 0);` and failed to achieve desired result. Putting breakpoint on `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` handler in subclassing proedure, and running debugger, I have seen that upon dialog creation I never reach that breakpoint. It is as if I haven't subclassed window at all. I am out of ideas at the moment...

Comment: Are you sure your dialog itself isn't receiving `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`? I can do more tests later... even if what Jonathan Potter says is right, who knows what the parent actually is (and this even assumes date-time pickers send out `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`). I can run my own tests later.

Comment: @andlabs: *Are you sure your dialog itself isn't receiving WM_CTLCOLOREDIT?* Haven't tried that. Still, I have tried subclassing month calendar in response to `DTN_DROPDOWN` and it worked, but I never received `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` message. Docs say that month calendar is created on arrow click, and destroyed when user clicks on arrow or chooses date. Even if subclassing would pass, I would have to subclass each time user presses arrow button/chooses date... * I can run my own tests later.* Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Importing for reference/to keep everything in one place: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930037/how-to-change-background-color-of-sysdatetimepick32-or-cdatetimectrl http://comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32.narkive.com/0H8cHhw1/setting-color-for-sysdatetimepick32-control

Answer (score 1):

#### Results of my experiments with catching `WM_CTLCOLORxxx` in the parent window

The code is below. Without any arguments it merely prints which `WM_CTLCOLORxxx` messages comes in. With arguments it tries to change both the control color and the text background color (to differnt things, but based on your them for simplicity).

**Windows 7, no visual styles/Common Controls 5**: no `WM_CTLCOLORxx` messages; no change in colors
**Windows 7, visual styles/Common Controls 6**: several `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` messages, but setting colors seems to have no effect
**wine**: one `WM_CTLCOLREDIT` message, returned brush is applied but text background color is not

This is all with a 32-bit binary; I doubt using a  64-bit binary would change anything (at least, I hope not).

So merely checking the parent window for a `WM_CTLCOLORxxx` message won't work. This answer doesn't answer the question, but there's surely room for more experimentation (perhaps more subclassing tests?).

I looked at the visual styles/Common Controls 6 setup in Spy++ on Windows 7 and I didn't see any children of the date-time picker.

Hopefully this helps for now.

```
// 17 february 2015
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define STRICT
#define STRICT_TYPED_ITEMIDS
#define CINTERFACE
#define COBJMACROS
// get Windows version right; right now Windows XP
#define WINVER 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0501       /* according to Microsoft's winperf.h */
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0600            /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x05010000    /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HWND dtp;
BOOL returnColors = FALSE;

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
#define CTLCOLOR(which) \
    case which: \
        printf("%s %p\n", #which, (HWND) lParam); \
        if (returnColors) { \
            SetBkColor((HDC) wParam, GetSysColor(COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION)); \
            return (LRESULT) GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_GRADIENTACTIVECAPTION); \
        } \
        break; /* fall through to DefWindowProc() */
    CTLCOLOR(WM_CTLCOLORMSGBOX)
    CTLCOLOR(WM_CTLCOLOREDIT)
    CTLCOLOR(WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX)
    CTLCOLOR(WM_CTLCOLORBTN)
    CTLCOLOR(WM_CTLCOLORDLG)
    CTLCOLOR(WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR)
    CTLCOLOR(WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC)
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icc;
    WNDCLASSW wc;
    HWND mainwin;
    MSG msg;

    returnColors = argc > 1;

    ZeroMemory(&icc, sizeof (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX));
    icc.dwSize = sizeof (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icc.dwICC = ICC_DATE_CLASSES;
    if (InitCommonControlsEx(&icc) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "InitCommonControlsEx() failed: %I32u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof (WNDCLASSW));
    wc.lpszClassName = L"mainwin";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (RegisterClassW(&wc) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "RegisterClassW() failed: %I32u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    mainwin = CreateWindowExW(0,
        L"mainwin", L"Main Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        320, 240,
        NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if (mainwin == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "create main window failed: %I32u", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    dtp = CreateWindowExW(0,
        DATETIMEPICK_CLASSW, L"",
        DTS_LONGDATEFORMAT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        20, 20, 200, 180,
        mainwin, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if (dtp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "create date-time picker failed: %I32u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("dtp %p\n", dtp);

    ShowWindow(mainwin, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(mainwin);

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. I can not accept it officially because it does not solve the problem I have. I know about macro [DateTime_GetDateTimeInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761786(v=vs.85).aspx) that might help. I have read somewhere in the docs ( I just can not remember where...) that month calendar is recreated each time user clicks on button. Same goes for edit control I think -> I must verify this with some tests. I am not sure. If this is not true then maybe there is a way to subclass edit control and change its background...

Comment: You could use that, but `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` is still sent to the /parent/ of the edit window. I don't know if it's such a good idea to subclass windows you don't know about (`GetParent()`), but you could at least figure out what it is and try that? Personally that's a bit far in the "undocumented internal structure" tank (for window hierarchy, anyway) for me but YMMV

Comment: I have nearly managed to solve the problem. See the edit in my OP. Just a few tweaks and its done. Can you try to help me with this one? Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff That isn't really going to work; I think I understand what you're trying to do with `TransparentBlt()` but there are still other reasons it won't work, and no, [you can't just graft transparent text rendering like that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/01/29/10589474.aspx). You're going to have to override `WM_PAINT` and `WM_PRINTCLIENT` and do all the drawing yourself. You're not entirely on your own, as the uxtheme API has date/time picker support, and obscure behaviors can be easily tested with the real thing, but...