# Win32 DateTime_SetMonthCalColor seems not work

Tags: winapi

I want to change the background color of a datetimepicker contorl's calender. According windows SDK ,there's a marco DateTime_SetMonthCalColor.

```
DateTime_SetMonthCalColor(hwnd,MSC_BACKGROUND,RGB(0,120,250));
```

But not work. I do this on windows control spy,send the same message DTM_SETMCCOLOR , no effect either. So what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

`MCSC_BACKGROUND` sets the background color of the [month calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/month-calendar-controls) control itself, which only shows when the dropdown is resized to more than the default single month. The background of individual months is set with `MCSC_MONTHBK` instead.

[image]

The month calendar control gets created each time the dropdown is opened. In order to resize it, the parent window of the date-time picker control must process the [`DTN_DROPDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/dtn-dropdown) notification, like in the minimal example below.

```
HWND CreateDTC(HWND hWnd)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex = { sizeof(icex), ICC_DATE_CLASSES };
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    return CreateWindowExW(0, DATETIMEPICK_CLASS, L"DateTime",
                           WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | DTS_SHOWNONE,
                           10, 10, 150, 25, hWnd, nullptr, hInst, nullptr);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hDTC = nullptr;

    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hDTC = CreateDTC(hWnd);
        DateTime_SetMonthCalColor(hDTC, MCSC_BACKGROUND, RGB(0, 120, 250)); // blue
        DateTime_SetMonthCalColor(hDTC, MCSC_MONTHBK, RGB(120, 250, 0));    // green
        break;

    case WM_NOTIFY:
        switch(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
        {
        case DTN_DROPDOWN:
            HWND hMC = DateTime_GetMonthCal(hDTC);
            RECT rc;
            MonthCal_GetMinReqRect(hMC, &rc);
            MoveWindow(hMC, 0, 0, (5 * rc.right) / 2, (3 * rc.bottom) / 2, FALSE);
            break;
        }
        break;
    //...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow,Nothing is more convincing than real code. Whats above pointed out where I'm wrong. Thank you @dxiv . 
If I want to change the background of the input box, what should I do ? the control doesn't provide a marco or message  or function calling interface.

Comment: @Younth Don't know that there is a ready made API for that. You'll probably have to subclass the date-time control and override `WM_ERASEBKGND` or `WM_PAINT` or possibly both.

Comment: that's what make me confused. See the component of the DTP control , the structure DATETIMEPICKERINFO, there's a edit sub control . I think that's what you called for doing subclass, right ? But according to windows spy , the DTP has no child control such as Edit. What's going on ?

Comment: @Younth No, I meant [window subclassing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) of the control itself. For the date-time control you can find some pointers at [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28511802/date-and-time-picker-with-visual-styles-enabled-change-background-color-of-the), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930037/how-to-change-background-color-of-sysdatetimepick32-or-cdatetimectrl), [3](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30660/A-DateTimePicker-with-working-BackColor), but it's not exactly straightforward.

Comment: I tried , not work , WM_ERASEBKGND not work. WM_PAINT make a mess which need me to redraw the whole control . What I expected is to change the background color. your links show some discuss , no exact solution. It seems to be a hard problem.@dxiv Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Younth Thing is that, unlike other common controls, the date time picker does not expose a "hook" to override the background color of its edit control. Whether by design or by accident, this means that any such customization can only be hack'ish. It gets even worse if you must support different/older versions of Windows and theme combinations.  You could post a new question about this, which would give it better visibility on SO, but I don't know that anybody has a magic answer to it.