# How to change the background color of the DateTime Picker control?

Tags: windows, winapi

[image: DTP]

As the picture shows,how to change the background color the DTP edit zone?

Frankly , I am very curious about so much referring WM_CTLCOLOREDIT , Did you ever make it work ? Each time, there would be someone referring to `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`, I tried , not work. Someone mentioned `WM_PRINT` to copy the original painting , and then , do some tricks to update the original paintings , pixel by pixel , like this,[image], it is a way , not proper, but a way.

Comment: Have a look at the [`DTM_SETMCCOLOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/dtm-setmccolor) window message. If that doesn't work, then you will have to subclass the DTP to handle the `WM_PAINT` and `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` window messages directly (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28511802/) and [this](https://comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32.narkive.com/0H8cHhw1/setting-color-for-sysdatetimepick32-control)).

Comment: See the links in my previous comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66310217/win32-datetime-setmonthcalcolor-seems-not-work/66381099#comment117355961_66381099).

Comment: @RemyLebeau if rewrite WM_PAINT ，can you edit the value of this control ? There is no Edit control as far as I tried.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Your answer show some information , though not work, thank you.
Just make it clear, ```DTM_SETMCCOLOR``` works for the drop down control calendar , not for the showing part which I'm now asking for answers. It doesn't work normally. There is something referring to Microsoft virtual style, which I have figured out. If you just want to modify the color of the drop-down calendar, no need to do subclassing or anything else.

Comment: @dxiv I can rewrite the WM_PAINT, but also I want to keep the circled out part can be edited.

Comment: Using ```WM_PRINT``` to copy the original painting and then rewrite ```WM_PAINT```,  here the tricks , handle the original part , update the background , pixels by pixels ， very tricky, the implement by @c00000fd is a way , not properly , but a way.